# Possible to run two completely different x-path

Tags: xpath, visual-web-developer

Can anyone please help me here ?
I want to run two xpath together and store the value, I am not sure if it is possible.
My one xpath is fetching City and second is state

```
//div[(text()='city')]/following-sibling::div

//div[contains(text(),'state')]/following-sibling::div
```

As xpath is telling name of city and state is provided in next div of city and state. I want to run both and capture output in string format.
On side note:   both xpath is working fine for me.

```
<div>
<div>City</div>
<div>London</div>
</div>
<--In between some other elements like p, section other divs-->
<div>
<div>state</div>
<div>England</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your exact expected output given your sample html and what version of xpath is available to you?

Comment: Do you want to combine both XPath’s into one and have to strings as return?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to convert the results of the two XPath expressions to strings, and concatenate those strings. The expression below concatenates them (with a single space between) using the XPath [`concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat) function.

```xml
concat(
   //div[(text()='city')]/following-sibling::div,
   ' ',
   //div[contains(text(),'state')]/following-sibling::div 
)
```

One other thing: note that in your example XML the text of the first `div` is "City" rather than "city". Make sure the strings in your XPath expression match the text exactly because the expression `'City'='city'` evaluates to `false`